# AnyLogic: Is there any implicit method to set pedEscalator's "Escalators" field dynamically?

Tags: anylogic

In case we have multiple escalator groups (maybe many) and we want our `ped` to choose one of them based on its final destination, is there any implicit way (as it seems there no explicit method) to set `Escalators` field of `pedEscalator` block dynamically? In order to avoid using many `pedEscalator` blocks and simpler model.

Comment: I don't see your problem... you can set escalators dynamically in the block itself.... and you can even set the escalator choice policy dynamically... I don't understand your struggle

Comment: I mean I can't use `ped` keyword and use one of its parameters or variables as the block `Escalators` field. Note that there are two fields, one `Escalators` and one `Escalator` which is shown when escalator choice policy is set to be custom. I am speaking about the former. Also when I hover mouse over `Escalators` equal sign, there are two choices: one value editor and one static value (In contrary to for example, `Direction` field)

Comment: I understand now.. you will have to use multiple pedEscalators... there's no other way as far as I know... you may be able to create a custom block with multiple pedescalators in it if you want your model to look cleaner

Comment: Thanks. In case of using a custom block; How can I use `ped` keyword in the custom block's parameter. Then only available keyword when hovering over bulb symbol is `self`.

Comment: you can't ... you have to use ped inside the custom block... shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Maybe I can, I changed my custom block's parameter type in advance menu from static to dynamic, and an argument menu appeared in my parameter's properties, in which I can define arguments like `ped` and their type. But the problem is that I don't know how to use it, because when I run the model everywhere I've used that parameter an error of `pedService_1 cannot be resolved to a variable.` is generated. Can you help me on how to use dynamic parameters in custom blocks?

Comment: Imagine a scenario. A crowd metro station, where based on peds current location and their destination, they would choose different escalators or `pedServices`. the overall logic is simple, for example each ped first selects an escalator then a `pedService`. so the real needed flowchart needs only two blocks. but because of `pedService` and `escalator` static parameters, we may need as many blocks as our physical equipment. You mean there is no way to solve it?

Comment: dynamic parameters won't help here... these parameters you use have nothing to do with the pedestrian you want to access... but in your custom block you can just use a selectOutput and select the output based on the pedestrian values... So I don't know why are you complicating yourself so much... I'm not even sure right now if using a custom block is what you need to do... I think you need to create a new question with details and screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183082/discussion-between-mohammad-hasan-n-and-felipe).